# Why does "for" not work inside batch file? (Works fine outside)

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

```
for /F "tokens=*" %* in (Test.txt) do md ".\%*" & cd "%*" & md "Something1" & md "Something2" & cd ".."
```

The DOS command will pull names from text file and create a named folder then two subfolders.

`Apple`
`-Something1`
`-Something2`

But when I put it into a batch file as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
@for /F "tokens=*" %* in (Test.txt) do md ".\%*" & cd "%*" & md "Something1" & md "Something2" & cd ".."
ECHO Done
PAUSE
```

Then run it from Windows GUI a sreen pops up, closes, and does nothing.  Even if I create a batch with the working DOS command it does nothing.  What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried leaving `ECHO ON` to see if it tells you anything?

Comment: ...and because you have called `@echo off`, the second @ (in front of the `for`) is pointless. But you would need to remove this to see any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In batch files, you need to double the '%' in the `for` variable. Don't ask me why. :)

Comment: Because a single % is the start of a variable name, like %UserName%.  You need to escape it for `For` to see a % rather than the contents of a variable.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food A single % is also the start of a variable name on the command line..

Answer (score 2):

This variation works for me:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('type foo.txt') do (
                md ".\%%g"
                cd "%%g"
                md "Something1"
                md "Something2"
                cd ".."
        )
endlocal
```

I chose to put the series of commands between parentheses and one on a line. Your chain of `&`-separated commands should work as well.

The `setlocal`/`endlocal` block limits the scope of variables. The `enabledelayedexpansion` argument enables some extra features in `cmd`. It isn't normally needed because it's the default for CMD, but that default might have been changed via policy, so it's a good practice to include it.

I prefer using `pushd` / `popd` over `cd blah` / `cd ..` in scripts. I think it's more robust.

Comment: Your solution was the original way I was going, but when I just couldn’t get anything going in my batch files I whittled my program down to the bare minimum.  Thank you.